# firebase verify id token gives: Firebase ID token has incorrect "iss"

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication

How do I verify `idToken` sent from the client on the server?

I am following the [docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) using python. Basically I signed in on the client with `email` and `password` which returns the `idToken`, and then I send this `idToken` to server for verification, but got the error as below.

> ValueError: Firebase ID token has incorrect "iss" (issuer) claim.
>   Expected "https://securetoken.google.com/myproject" but got
>   "https://identitytoolkit.google.com/". Make sure the ID token comes
>   from the same Firebase project as the service account used to
>   authenticate this SDK. See
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for
>   details on how to retrieve an ID token.

I am pretty sure I generated the service account json in the same project as the client. Does anybody know what could be the issue?

My Server code looks like this:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, initialize_app, auth

def is_authenticated(id_token):
    cred = credentials.Certificate("service-account.json")
    app = initialize_app(cred)
    return auth.verify_id_token(id_token, app)
```

Answer (score 27):

Besides sending the email and password, you also have to set the flag `returnSecureToken` to `true`, otherwise your IdToken will not be valid and you will also not get a refresh token.

```
curl 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"email":"[user@example.com]","password":"[PASSWORD]","returnSecureToken":true}'
```

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I followed the wrong docs on the client side; Eventually I followed [this docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients), and used the following code to extract the `idToken` which I sent to backend for verification:

```js
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```